# C++Builder VCL array of buttons dynamically made each with his independent click action

Tags: c++, c++builder, vcl

i have tried the following way but it doesn't seem to work and it is incomplete.

```
void __fastcall TForm1::Button1Click(TObject *Sender) 
{
    TButton **ButtonArray = NULL;
    ButtonArray = new TButton*[5];

    for(int x = 0; x < 5; ++x) 
    {
        ButtonArray[x] = new TButton(this);
        ButtonArray[x]->Caption = (AnsiString)"teste " + x + " - " + (1+random(100));
        ButtonArray[x]->Left = 25 + 4 * random(100);
        ButtonArray[x]->Top = 25 + 4 * random(100);
    }
}
```

Code compiles without problems, but no button seems to show. Also, there is no action and buttons in the array have a predefined max of 5.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To make them visible in your form you must set the Parent property of your buttons.

```
ButtonArray[ x ]->Parent = this;
```

There's no action because you do not set one.

```
void __fastcall TForm1::ButtonClick(TObject *Sender)
{
   MessageBox( Handle, L"Hello", L"Message", MB_OK );
}
```

And when creating your buttons...

```
ButtonArray[ x ]->OnClick = ButtonClick;
```

Comment: Yes, this resolved my problem and one more thing  is there any better place to add these buttons like on vs on grids/stack panels ?

Comment: @VladVlad: that should be posted as a new question.